# Integration by parts for deriving gamma function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, special-functions

Well, there is an integral that has quite a lot to do with $n!$, and that is the following :

$f(n)$ = `Integrate[x^(n - 1)/E^x, {x, 0, Infinity}]` =$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x} \, dx$ **(1)**

Integrate by parts the above gives

`parts[u_, v_] :=  (#1*Integrate[#2, x] - Integrate[D[#1, x]*Integrate[#2, x],  x] & )[u, v]`

`parts[x^(n - 1), E^(-x)]` = $-e^{-x} x^{n-1}-(n-1) \Gamma (n-1,x)$

How to get this result ? ( see **(1)** too )

[image]

Comment: To see the outcome of the integration in parts done in MMA in the form as noted in the box
That's the goal.
It is the factorial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

### **Using [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)**

---

```
Assuming[n > 0, 
 Integrate[x^(n - 1)/E^x, {x, 0, ∞}] /. 
  Gamma[x_] :> Factorial[x - 1]]
```

> `(-1 + n)!`

---

### **Using [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)**

---

```
gammatofac[x_, xx_] := 
  FullSimplify[x, xx ∈ Integers && xx > 0, 
   ComplexityFunction -> ((LeafCount@# + 
        10 Count[#, _Gamma | _Pochhammer, {0, ∞}]) &)];
```

and run the integration

```
gammatofac[Integrate[x^(n - 1)/E^x, {x, 0, ∞}], n]
```

> `(-1 + n)!`

Comment: bmf, Yes, that is the correct outcome, cleverly done!
Have seen this example as study text and the derivation is done manually.

Your elaboration shows that this does involve specialized MMA knowledge which I as a regular user do not have.

Comment: bmf, Starting with the outcome of the partial integration.
Can anything be derived from this?

Comment: @janhardo - "specialized MMA knowledge which I as a regular user do not have" ... You do if you use the readily available documentation.

Comment: @janhardo you could try for example `FullSimplify[(n - 1) Gamma[n - 1], Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]` but this gives back only `Gamma[n]`.

Comment: @janhardo you could also try a simple replacement rule -see update.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon - Thanks for the encouragement to look into it a little further

Comment: @bmf -Now I need to get clear on what this ComplexityFunction stands for?

Comment: @janhardo I have added another way of getting the result which is simpler and it works in this case. I think you should be familiar with that. I have added links to the documenation so you can have a read on `ComplexityFunction`

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your definition of `parts` does not consider the interval of integration. Change the definition to

```
parts[u_, dv_, interval_List] :=
 Module[{v = Integrate[dv, x]},
  Limit[u*v, x -> interval[[-1]]] -
   Limit[u*v, x -> interval[[-2]]] - 
   Integrate[D[u, x]*v, interval]]

Assuming[n > 1, parts[x^(n - 1), E^-x, {x, 0, Infinity}]]

(* Gamma[n] *)

% /. Gamma[z_] :> (z - 1)! // TraditionalForm

(* (n-1)! *)
```

Comment: Bob Hanlon- thanks ,I overlooked that the integration intervals when I used the code for the integration in parts.
You did tackle it thoroughly by using this with module programming.